# Make the "Ultimate Member" registration form multi-page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, multipage, ultimate-member

I have created a fairly long registration form using the Ultimate Member plugin for Wordpress and would like to turn it into a multi-page form. The current form is added to my registration page using the shortcode: `[ultimatemember form_id=161]`.

According to Ultimate Member this is the template that needs to be modified:

```
<div class="um <?php echo $this->get_class( $mode ); ?> um-<?php echo $form_id; ?>">

<div class="um-form">

    <form method="post" action="">

    <?php

        do_action("um_before_form", $args);

        do_action("um_before_{$mode}_fields", $args);

        do_action("um_main_{$mode}_fields", $args);

        do_action("um_after_form_fields", $args);

        do_action("um_after_{$mode}_fields", $args);

        do_action("um_after_form", $args);

    ?>

    </form>

</div>
```

Any suggestions as to how this could be best achieved?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?